# Rspec controller spec resulting in failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My RSpec for ResidenceInformations Controller is resulting in failure when I run 'rake spec'. My Controller code is as follows

```
class ResidenceInformationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
    render partial: 'subregion_select'
  end

  def new
    @residence_info = ResidenceInformation.new
    @saved_residence_info = ResidenceInformation.where('applicant_id=?', current_applicant.id)
  end

  def create
    @residence_info = ResidenceInformation.new(residence_informations_params)
    @residence_info.state = params[:order][:state]
    @residence_info.applicant_id = current_applicant.id
    #@residence_info.residence_type_id = params[:residence_type][:residence_type_id]
    @residence_info.save!
    if cookies[:residence_next] == 'true' && cookies[:add_another] == 'false'
      redirect_to new_employment_information_path
    elsif cookies[:residence_next] == 'false' && cookies[:add_another] == 'true'
      #cookies[:add_another] = 'false'
      redirect_to request.referer
    elsif cookies[:residence_next] == 'false' && cookies[:add_another] == 'false'
      redirect_to request.referer
    end
  end

  def edit
    @residence_info = ResidenceInformation.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update

  end

  def destroy
  end

  def subregion_options
    render partial: 'subregion_select'
  end

  private

  def residence_informations_params
    params.require(:residence_information).permit(:address1, :address2, :country, :state, :city, :zip, :reason_for_moving, :resident_since, :resident_upto, :was_notice_given, :monthly_rent, :residence_type_id, :applicant_id)
  end
end
```

And This is my spec file for the above mentioned controller

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ResidenceInformationsController, :type => :controller do

  describe 'GET #new' do

    login_applicant

    it 'should have a current_applicant' do
      subject.current_applicant.should_not be_nil
    end

    it 'assigns a new ResidenceInformation to @residenceinfo' do
      #residenceinfo = FactoryGirl.create(:residence_information, address1: 'dsada', country: 'india', state: 'wb', city: 'kolkata', zip: '700091', reason_for_moving: 'none', resident_since: '2015-01-05', was_notice_given: 'true', residence_type_id: 1, applicant_id: 13)
      #puts"****************#{residenceinfo.inspect}***********************"
      get :new
      assigns(:residenceinfo).should be_a_new(ResidenceInformation)
    end

    it 'renders the :new template' do
      get :new
      response.should render_template :new
    end

  end

  describe 'POST create' do

    login_applicant

    context 'with valid attributes' do

      it 'should have a current_applicant' do
        subject.current_applicant.should_not be_nil
      end

      it 'create a new ResidenceInformation' do
        expect{
          post :create, residenceinformation: FactoryGirl.create(:residence_information, address1: 'dsada', country: 'india', state: 'wb', city: 'kolkata', zip: '700091', reason_for_moving: 'none', resident_since: '2015-01-05', was_notice_given: 'true', residence_type_id: 1, applicant_id: 13)
        }.to change(ResidenceInformation, :count).by(1)
      end

    end

  end

end
```

I am getting the following error when running this spec file

```
Failure/Error: assigns(:residenceinfo).should be_a_new(ResidenceInformation)
       expected nil to be a new ResidenceInformation(id: integer, address1: string, address2: string, country: string, state: string, city: string, zip: string, monthly_rent: integer, reason_for_moving: string, resident_since: date, resident_upto: date, was_notice_given: boolean, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, residence_type_id: integer, applicant_id: integer)
     # ./spec/controllers/residence_informations_controller_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

As I am completely new to RSpec , so I would appreciate any kind of help I get from you people. Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Sorry , I had given the wrong spec file. now given the right one

Comment: The file quoted above is `./spec/controllers/residence_informations_controller_spec.rb`? 
I would expect to see the assertion cited in the failure to be in the spec file itself, i.e.
`assigns(:residenceinfo).should be_a_new(ResidenceInformation)`

Comment: @anyarms Sorry I had given the wrong spec file code. Now I have given the right one and also made the change that you suggested but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your instance variable is named `@residence_info` and you are checking `:residenceinfo`. Try it with the underscore:

```
assigns(:residence_info).should be_a_new(ResidenceInformation)
```